How do I start using a database(lowDB) and implement it into my code?
Can anyone help me understand how to implement lowDB into my discord.js code, I am kind of lost and only recently started.
I've tried to search tutorials on youtube on several occasions but nothing has appeared, and the discord.js documentation seems outdated. then I had tried searching it up on stack overflow but nothing has came up on it, in simplest terms I am cooked without help

If you're referring to typicode/lowdb, I'd highly recommend not using it as it is JSON file based. There are several reasons why not to use JSON files as database (see this answer here). TLDR; JSON files are poorly optimized to act as databases and are prone to data loss. As your user base grows, your db will become very slow. You're much better off using an established database service. MongoDB Atlas being a popular example for Discord bots.
